# I can't display json with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I need to display the products array from a json with v-for but I'm not able to.

I'm trying to display json data from the products array but it's not working.

**Vue.js**

```
<div class="box" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
  <h2>Produto {{ product.name }}</h2>
  <h3>Situação {{ product.situation }}</h3>
</div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      try {
        const req = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/products");
        const data = await req.json();
        this.products = data.products;
        console.log("data" + data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getData();
    },
  },
};
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "a898",
      "name": "Claudio Romano",
      "situation": "Ativo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong question, because the problem has nothing to do with the JSON. If you debug this, you'll notice the console.logs don't execute, meaning the problem is much more fundamental because the method itself isn't actually running.

The root problem is that `mounted()` is not supposed to be inside `methods`.  You're using Vue's Options API where `data()`, `methods` and `mounted` are all separate, individual "options".  You need to move mounted outside of methods, it should be a "sibling" option as it were.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  },
};
```

[Playground demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)